# How to hide options of jquery choosen dropdownlistbox after clicking on it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I am developing jquery application. I am trying to hide some of the options of choosen dropdown immediately after clicking on it. I am able to hide option but problem is when i click on drodpownbox i can see all the option and if i select any option then required option will hide. What i want is after clicking on the dropdown immediately before showing options i want to hide.

```
 var checkedValues = [];
        $("#<%=gdvRegretletter.ClientID %> tr").each(function () {
            if ($(this).closest('tr').find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', true)) {
                checkedValues.push($(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(2)').text().trim());
            }
        });
        $('.limitedNumbSelect').change(function (e) {

           //i want to hide here.
             $(".limitedNumbSelect  option").each(function () {
                 var val = $(this).val();
                 alert(val);
          //Here i am able to hide.
                 var display = checkedValues.indexOf(val) === -1;
                 $(this).toggle(display);
                 $('.limitedNumbSelect option[value=' + display + ']').hide();
                 $(".limitedNumbSelect").find('option:contains(' + display + ')').remove().end().chosen();
             });
        });
```

I do not have any idea how to achieve it here. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Why not remove the `<option>` elements you want to hide *before* the `<select>` is focused?

Comment: Thank you David. I tried. No Luck. As soon as i click dropdown below options will come. If i select anyone option later my required option will hide.

Comment: Is there any event such that as soon as i click on drodpwn i want to hide some of the options?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] in order for us to reproduce your problem, and to clarify: it needs to be *minimal*, we don't need all the details, just enough that we can see what you're working with in order to propose a valid solution.

Comment: Okay thank you. Just i want to work like as below.   $('.limitedNumbSelect').click(function (e) {
            alert("I am going crazy");
        });

Comment: Will it do if you save all your options in offline Json Object in Key Value pair. Now, when you select Option 1, you can do your processing => delete it from your json object => re-build your SELECT using updated Json object